# Compactness of topologists curve.

Tags: general-topology

The “topologist’s curve” is supposedly not locally compact. In any neighborhood of a point nearer to the origin there are multiple segments, in circular basis the centermost segment ought to have a least upper bound, while in square basis they all have equal, disjoint upper bounds.

- I just don't see why it isn't locally compact or anything; even though I have studied a lot.

Comment: Are you referring to the “topologist’s sine curve?” https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topologist's_sine_curve?wprov=sfti1

Comment: Yes that one is what I need help with, thanks

Comment: Is the origin a point in the curve?

Comment: It is just by a union -

Comment: Okay now if the circle has the discrete segments in it and one is higherin value than the others it is a least upper bound of the all segments, and the same is true for the square neighborhoods because then the values are obviously then equal to one and other

Comment: I think I have it now, the y axis is not included.... Now I just don't get why $0$ must be the image of $\{-1\}$.

Comment: You seem to be saying compact but meaning connected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may clear things up if you note that the spaces you are considering have the subspace topology. And the point is that $f$ is $\textit{defined}$ on the locally compact space $S=\{-1\}\cup (0,1]$ to be $(x,\sin(1/x))$ if $x>0$ and $f(-1)=(0,0)$, to show that a continuous function need not preserve local compactness. And $f$ is indeed continuous: the only point that might need checking for continuity of $f$ is $x=-1.$ A neighborhood $V$ of $(0,0)$ in the topologist's sine curve $T$ is $T\cap U$ for some open set $U$ in $\mathbb R^2$ that contains $(0,0).$ So $T\cap U=\{(0,0)\}\cup \{(x,\sin(1/x)):x\in (0,\epsilon)\}$ Then $f^{-1}(V)=\{-1\}\cup (0,\epsilon)$ which is open in $S$.

And yet, $T$ itself is not locally compact because for an arbitrary $V$ as above $\text{cl}_TV=\{(0,0)\}\cup \{(x,\sin(1/x)):x\in (0,\epsilon]\}$ is not compact: we find a sequence in $T$ with no convergent subsequence (in $T$!). One possibility is $s_n=(2/(2n+1)\pi,1)$ because $s_n\to (0,1)\notin T.$

Comment: Would you please explain why sequences are used in your second paragraph for showing compactness because I am having trouble with reading it. If a subset was compact, then to me that just means it contains it's limit points and the subset is bounded as a subset. However sequences are used very much and I only have tested them for convergence \ divergence way before this-- why consider all of the random sequences?

Comment: In a metric space you can use sequences to show or disprove compactness.My answer shows that for $any$ neighborhood of $(0,0),$ its closure in $T$ is not compact, by producing a sequence (there are many) in that has no convergent subsequence in it

Comment: Thank you very much; I presume that $ : (0, \epsilon]$ is a ball and, the set $0\times[-1,1]$ is the closure so points don't converge to the limit points as a subset of $R 
 \times R$ however it is a subspace topology and that closure isnt really counted for in this problem so thank you for the help and thanks again "if you would explain why if the line $0 \times [-1,1]$ isnt in the subspace topology then, how is the set not compact"....